# Passing a pointer of a template class property

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I know there is a similar question but I want something more general.
I want to use a template class and to use a template function.
It Would be clearer with example:
I got is segment of working code

```
private T[][] fCreateStabsTable<T>(int p_iRows) 
    {
        T[][] l_tTabel  = new T [p_iRows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < p_iRows; i++)
        {
            l_tTabel[i] = new T[m_iNumOfStabsItems];

            for (int j = 0; j < m_iNumOfStabsItems; j++)
            {
                l_tTabel[i][j] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(m_oStabilites[i][j].Text,typeof(T));
            }
        }

        return l_tTabel;
    }
```

I want to make it more general, to pass a 2D template source array and to pass to the function the property it needs to call.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
private T1[][] fCreateTable<T1, T2, T3>(int p_iRows, int p_iCols, T2[][] p_t2Source, Func<T2, string> p_fProperty)
    {
        T1[][] l_tTabel = new T1[p_iRows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < p_iRows; i++)
        {
            l_tTabel[i] = new T1[p_iCols];

            for (int j = 0; j < p_iCols; j++)
            {
                l_tTabel[i][j] = (T1)Convert.ChangeType(p_t2Source[i][j].p_fProperty, typeof(T));
            }
        }
        return l_tTabel;
    }
```

Can it be done? How can I implement this?

Comment: So you're trying to pass the **property** which the Convert call should use?

Comment: Not exactly it the property I want to pass to the Convert.